# SQL Разбрасывает значение по ячейкам, что делать?

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot

Я первый раз работаю с sql и мне понадобилось создать базу данных, в которую позже я буду вводить значения, вот создание базы:

```
    def create_db(self):
    self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name VARCHAR (255),
        balance INTEGER,
        gold INTEGER,
        lvl INTEGER);
    """)
    self.connection.commit()
```

если я вписываю значения в ячейку, то выходит такая вот фигня
[image: Как это пофиксить?]

Вот весь код:
[image: код]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) + [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Comment: А ещё, код нифига не весь, а ошибка вполне очевидна.

Comment: это не SQL расбрасывает все по ячейкам, а Вы. Просто Вы для вставки одного значения в одну ячейку вставляете целую строку!  Вам нужно вставлять сразу все значения одной строкой `INSERT INTO users (name, gold, balance, lvl) VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?);` либо позже обновлять из через `UPDATE users SET name=? WHERE id=?;`...кстати, где ваш ID?

Comment: `INSERT ... VALUES ` вставляет не менее одной строки...сколько будет скобок `( ... )` со значениями после `VALUES` столько и строк он вставит... он не может вставлять `"по одной ячейке"`